# iOS Video Playback Performance Simulator vs. Device

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

I'm currently working on a kiosk app. The core of this functionality is a single movie-player view controller. The app will cycle through various movie files, as well as displaying UI elements are various locations based on what movie is currently being played.

Here's where I set-up the view controller's `avPlayer`:

```
func initPlayer() {


setAvPlayerItem()

avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)

avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
avPlayerLayer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
movieView.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)

notificationCenter.removeObserver(self,
                                  name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                  object: avPlayer.currentItem)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                               selector: #selector(avPlayerDidPlayToEndTime),
                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                               object: avPlayer.currentItem)

avPlayer.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
avPlayer.volume = 0.0
avPlayer.play()
}
```

Here's where I play the current movie:

```
func playCurrentMovie() {
setAvPlayerItem()

avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: avPlayerItem)

notificationCenter.removeObserver(self,
                                  name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                  object: avPlayer.currentItem)

notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                               selector: #selector(avPlayerDidPlayToEndTime),
                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                               object: avPlayer.currentItem)

avPlayer.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
avPlayer.volume = 0.0
avPlayer.play()
}
```

...and here's where I set what `avPlayerAsset` should be used:

```
func setAvPlayerItem()  {


let resource = moviesCollection[currentMovie]["Movie"] as! String?

guard let moviePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource,
                                       ofType:"mp4") else {
    debugPrint("video not found")
    return
}

movieURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath)
avAsset = AVAsset(url: movieURL)

avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
}
```

This works perfectly on the Simulator. When running on a device (iPad Pro 12.9"), there is a black flicker on the screen every time I advance to have a new video asset play.

Does anyone have an idea why that black flicker may be occuring?

Comment: I am not sure what causes a black flicker, however, What I can tell you is avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: avPlayerItem) blocks the UI for a small ammount of time, and there is no way around it. not sure if this is the problem tho, but a hint only.

Comment: @Sneak Ok, that does make sense. Is there another (better) way to switch out items?

Comment: There is NO other way around this unfortunatly, I even have a bounty up atm for this. However, since your files are local if you don't have that many movies to cycle through , you can try to setup an `AVQueuePlayer` , and "preload" all the `playerItems` and queue them up, cycle through them accordingly to what you want to play. I have not tested the performance of this, but it is logical that you shouldnt do this if you have way to many videos to cycle through.

Comment: @Sneak That makes sense, thanks! Do you know if there's any upper limit on how many videos `AVQueuePlayer` can pre-load?

Comment: the documentation doesnt say anything about it I think, however, You can simply test this by creating the array with the AVPlayerItems and see how much memory is allocated and how the performance is , unless you find an answer out there. However, always best to test yourself :)

Comment: btw, you should also check to implement KVO loading of the AVAsset asynchronously might reduce some lags loading the assets. Check this Apple Example on how to do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Listings/Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerViewController_swift.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot to prevent this black flicker with no success. However I did come up with a way to hide it from the user.

First I made a super simple view that wraps the `AVPlayerLayer` called `videoView` in this example. Then I added that view as a subview of my video player view. Then whenever I go to load a new video I do:

```
if let snapshotView = playerView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false) {
    insertSubview(snapshotView, belowSubview: videoView)
    snapshotView.frame = videoView.bounds
}

let item: AVPlayerItem = ...
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
// The rest of your loading like normal
```

Just make sure to remove the `snapshotView` if you support clearing your video or whatever.

Comment: Is this solution still working for you on iOS 12? I'm in a similar situation and seeing this black frame on simulator and device.